# ORMLite can't create row with unique combo in android

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

This is the table fields i have defined:

```
@DatabaseField(uniqueCombo = true, columnName = COLUMN_NAME_FEED_PROVIDER_TYPE, canBeNull = false)
private int mFeedProviderType;
@DatabaseField(uniqueCombo = true, columnName = COLUMN_NAME_FEED_PROVIDER_SUB_TYPE)
private String mSubType; 
@DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_NAME_DATE, canBeNull = false)
private long mDate;
```

I've managed to add 1 row. But when i try to add the second row this time changing the mSubType String field, it throws and except:

```
at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:135)
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.create(StatementExecutor.java:450)
at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.create(BaseDaoImpl.java:310)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.insert(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java:169)
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:91)
at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.insert(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java:155)
```

Answer (score 0):

even you use uniqueCombo,  you need an id also .So add an generatedId annotation like this:

```
@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
private int _id;//主键id
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.